# Inside a stored procedure. How can I tell if an UPDATE worked?

Tags: sql-server

I have:

```
    UPDATE Table1
    SET    Col1 = 'X'
    WHERE  Val1 = @Val1
```

How can I tell if this found a row to update or not?

Also I noticed SET NOCOUNT ON

Can someone tell me what this does?

Comment: Use `@@ROWCOUNT` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316%28v=sql.100%29.aspx     `NOCOUNT on` simply tells not to show  @@ROWCOUNT in your studio window

Comment: Can you give an example as an answer using IF so that I can accept the question. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  `@@ROWCOUNT` to retrieve number of rows affected by the executed statement. In the stored proc:

```
 UPDATE Table1
 SET    Col1 = 'X'
 WHERE  Col21 = @Val1

 If @@ROWCOUNT > 0
 begin
   -- execute more logic
   -- execute even more logic
 end
```

This is sufficient to know if update worked. You can use `Output Inserted....` logic to retrieve full details of your data changes. See it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Yep, exactly. that's how it must be. +1

Answer (score 0):

The command SET NOCOUNT ON in a stored procedure prevents sending a recordset back to the client with the rowcount details. The presence of this additional recordset can confuse libraries such as OLEDB and ADODB.

You can amend your UPDATE statement to look like this:

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET    Col1 = 'X'
    OUTPUT deleted.Val1, deleted.Col1 as old, inserted.COl1 as new
    WHERE  Val1 = @Val1
```

which will have the effect of returning a rowset with one row for each updated record.